# Ditto, but with git history

Tags: git

This seems impossible, but in my git repo I have the following:

```
/foo
    /bar
        somefile.txt
        somenewfile.txt
/bar
    somefile.txt
```

The contents of `/foo/bar` have become synonymous with `/bar` and I'd like to do exactly `ditto /foo/bar /bar`(that is, copy the contents of `/foo/bar` onto `/bar` where the former wins) but in some way preserve the change history of both `somefile.txt`'s and the new `somenewfile.txt` instead of attributing all the changes to whomever does the `ditto` command.

I want to be left with:

```
/bar
    somefile.txt
    somenewfile.txt
```

Are there some games I could play with `git subtree`, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Git is a content tracker, as opposed to some other SCM like bazaar which track the identity of files.  That means that apart from the information which files exist and what their contents are, there are no further clues about which file “is” which in a Git commit.

You can't do anything about that using `git subtree`.  But you don't have to, either: no information is lost during a rename, and a somewhat intelligent program (like `git gui` or `gitk`) will show you the correct information anyway.